# Finding if the orthonormal basis of P1 with a given inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

[image]

Hi,

So I know for a basis to be orthonormal, the inner product needs to be 0 between components.

So the standard basis <1,t> would not work in this case, as the integral from 1 to zero of t is t^2/2

Can <0,t> be a basis for p1?

Thanks

Comment: The zero vector can never be in a basis. Take $1,t$ and do Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: Why don't you just choose $f=1$ and find $g\in P_1$ which is orthogonal to $f$? You could do this by hand or apply Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: $0$ can't be a vector in any basis. Let the basis be $\{1,at+b\}$. Now use the inner product definition and find the coefficients that will make it orthonormal.

Comment: I see what I did, I can just do Gram-Schmidt